# Does keeping long-lived connections make a background script persistent regardless of its declared type?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, redux, webext-redux

I'd like to use Redux to store/manage the state in my chrome extension. I found [WebExt Redux](https://github.com/tshaddix/webext-redux) library which allows to use Redux with chrome extensions. But I have a concern about message ports that seem to be used there to sync the state between a background script and other extension's parts.

My background script is not supposed to be always active, so I registered it as non-persistent in the manifest.

If I understood correctly from the WebExt Redux [sources](https://github.com/tshaddix/webext-redux/blob/master/src/store/Store.js), creating a proxy store in a content script opens long-lived connection between the latter and the background script which seems to be never closed within the respective tab's lifetime.

According to Chrome API [Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages):

> the background page will not unload until all visible views and all
>   ***message ports*** are closed.

So does all the above means that my background script will never be unloaded as long as there is at least one tab opened in browser?

Comment: Yes it does mean that. This is one of the tricks to force the event page to persist.

Comment: @wOxxOm Is there a similar library without using persistent message ports?

Comment: Don't think so because how would it maintain the state? You can probably shut it down and start explicitly when needed based on some conditions. If there's no such capability in it, I think it'd make sense to suggest implementing it to the authors.